# PM Message System PHP not working

Tags: php, session

I'm currently working on a PM system (private message system). However, I am getting a error.

The error is:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\brickmarket\messages.php on line 18

I have tested this without the `WHERE to='" . $_SESSION["user_name"] . "'";` and that works fine and the error doesn't appear, so I am unsure what the issue is.

`$_SESSION["user_name"]` outputs the username of the currently logged in user.

My full code is:

```
<h1>My private messages</h1>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pb WHERE to='" . $_SESSION["user_name"] . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    ?>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td><strong>ID</strong></td><td><strong>From</strong></td><td><strong>To</strong></td><td><strong>Subject</strong></td><td><strong>Date</strong></td><td></td>
</tr>
    <?php
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td><td><?php echo $row["from"]; ?></td><td><?php echo $row["to"]; ?></td><td><?php echo $row["subject"]; ?></td><td><?php echo $row["date"]; ?></td><td><a href="">View</a></td>
</tr>
    <?php
    }
?>
</table>
<?php
} else {
    echo "You don't have any messages yet.";
}
?>
```

I hope someone can help me out, I'm fighting with my code for a few hours now.

---

PS: I know this code is vulnerable to SQL injection & will fix that later.

Comment: *"I have tested this without the WHERE to"* - That's because `to` is a MySQL reserved word and requires special treatment  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh okay, learned something new today!

Comment: We've all been down that road and will still find new trails to adventure ourselves on ;-) *Cheers*